# Angular | ControlValueAccessor to non native Input

Tags: angular, form-control, controlvalueaccessor

Is it possible to make a **custom** form control with **ControlValueAccessor** in Angular **NOT** using native element of the DOM (like input, textarea, radio button), but using plain div and span? I Have wandered Google in search of the answer to this particular question, but no luck unfortunately.

Comment: Unclear what you mean? Can you give examples?

Comment: So what kind of thing are you rendering (as input) inside the CVA element?

Answer (score 0):

`ControlValueAccessor` is just an interface used by angular forms to interact with your custom control and vice versa.

Therfore, your contol can be anything - and image(huh?), video(rly?), raw socket stream (thats reasonable), anything you can imagine - as long as it interacts with the form via that particular interface.

Comment: In my custom control I use only divs and spans. It doesn't seem to work properly...

Comment: Well that is another story. You can always share a code and ask for help on it. But here, you are dont since you have asked "is it possible" and the answer is yes.